# Where does JAVA tar.gz file gets downloaded when it installed by oracle-java9-installer package?

Tags: apt, software-installation, java, downloads

This question is related to [already existing question in askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre).

I installed Sun Java using `sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer`

**The procedure downloaded Java tar.gz file** like the logs below.

```
<trimmed>

Downloading Oracle Java 9... 
--2015-06-11 02:48:37--  http://www.java.net/download/jdk9/archive/b66/binaries/jdk-9-ea-bin-b66-linux-x64-27_may_2015.tar.gz 
Resolving www.java.net (www.java.net)... 209.189.227.38 
Connecting to www.java.net (www.java.net)|209.189.227.38|:80... connected. 
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found 
Location: https://www.java.net/download/jdk9/archive/b66/binaries/jdk-9-ea-bin-b66-linux-x64-27_may_2015.tar.gz [following] 
--2015-06-11 02:48:39--  https://www.java.net/download/jdk9/archive/b66/binaries/jdk-9-ea-bin-b66-linux-x64-27_may_2015.tar.gz 

<trimmed>

--2015-06-11 02:48:41--  http://download.java.net/jdk9/archive/b66/binaries/jdk-9-ea-bin-b66-linux-x64-27_may_2015.tar.gz?q=download/jdk9/archive/b66/binaries/jdk-9-ea-bin-b66-linux-x64-27_may_2015.tar.gz 
Resolving download.java.net (download.java.net)... 137.254.120.26 
Connecting to download.java.net (download.java.net)|137.254.120.26|:80... connected. 
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK 
Length: 117953013 (112M) [application/gzip] 
Saving to: ‘jdk-9-ea-bin-b66-linux-x64-27_may_2015.tar.gz’ 

<trimmed>

2015-06-11 03:00:39 (161 KB/s) - ‘jdk-9-ea-bin-b66-linux-x64-27_may_2015.tar.gz’ saved [117953013/117953013] 

Download done.
```

Install proceeded as expected in my computer and finished successfully. However **I would like to know download location of this xx.tar.gz file in current computer** so that I can make a copy of it along with downloaded *deb files in apt-cache. This is for replicating java installation on other similar computers without accessing the download site over internet  each time to get 112 M file. I looked at 
`$HOME/Downloads`, `/tmp` and `/var/cache/apt/archives`, 
but could not locate this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not related to apt-get at all.

Oracle-java9-installer has an installation script that downloads java from Oracle site and installs it. It is very specific to this package.

***But your answer is:*** the tarball is at **/var/cache/oracle-jdk9-installer/**

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer and correction to question.